# What if the HDFS file is too big to form the RDD within the workers of the node?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

Say there is a 20gb hdfs file, and you have 4 nodes(with 2gb ram each), so total 8gb available RAM, now how will that 20gb be loaded as RDD for processing.

Comment: _"If the **RAM** keeps all my data, why do we need a hard disk or a database?"_ - **RDDs** are ain memory data structures used for processing **HDFS** _(or another kind of storages like **S3** or **GCS**)_ are used for persisting data across different executions and different programs.

Comment: Thanks @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, one more doubt, what if the file size is too big to read from the HDFS, that it is not fit into the nodes of the workers ,even after partitioned. Say 20gb hdfs file, and you have 4 nodes(with 2gb ram), so total 8gb available RAM, now how will that 20gb be loaded as RDD for processing .

Comment: I am not an expert in the **Spark** internals but if you specify too little partitions, _(meaning each partition will be too big)_ you would get memory errors. If you specify many partitions then **Spark** will load each partition process and save it back - In any case, that is bad architecture, **Spark** was designed to keep all the data in memory in order to be fast.

Comment: In case of specifying partitions, i am confused with these two cases, case 1: Is number of partitions decided in the form of numbers(say i have 20gb file, and I need 5 partitions) or case 2: (say I have 20gb file , and I need partitions with each 2gb size, I don't care how many paritions forms up), which one is considered? And the question was how spark manages when the data is larger then the cluster memory?  @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, If you can have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59227822/where-is-the-intermediate-serialized-data-stored-before-sending-it-to-the-other

Comment: Partitions are specified in number, **Spark** decides the size of each one _(they are not equal)_ usually **Spark** decides the number automatically based on some conditions, but you can specify them manually. For the second question, if you do not force the  number of partitions, then **Spark** will simply create as many as necessary but if the size is too big, it either will be too slow or will crash, as I said, **Spark** is not designed for that cases. - Anyways, IMHO, instead of asking such broad questions in SO, you shoudl read the doc / tutorials and do some experiments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A 20GB file in HDFS is not stored as a single 20GB file, it's split into HDFS blocks of a configurable size, the default being 128MB.

If your file is splittable (such as text, avro, json, ORC, parquet, or certain archive formats) then those blocks are loaded individually into distinct Spark tasks

If too much data is loaded into an executor, it's allowed to spill to disk, but otherwise you're limited by the available amount of memory of the scheduler and executor node, otherwise the job ends with OOM